# Linq - How do I coalesce these into a single IQueryable?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, iqueryable

I have a simple (obfuscated) class:

```
public Thing ()
{
    public IList<string> Strings()
    { 
        // returns an IList of whatever, 
        // using strings as an example
    }
}
```

elsewhere in my code I retrieve an `IQueryable<Thing> things` from the database

My goal is to get all of the `string`s from the `things` into one `IQueryable<string> strings`, perhaps something like:

```
var strings = from t in things
              select t.Strings()
```

but that only gets me an `IQueryable<IList<string>>`.  How do I mush all of those lists into one all-encompassing collection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using something like:

```
things.SelectMany(t => t.Strings);
```

Comment: Simple - yet so elusive.  Thanks.